# python3 venv pip version conflict

Tags: pip, python-3.7

I have a PyCharm python 3.7.1 project on Windows 10.  In the project `venv\Scripts`  folder is `pip.exe`, `pip3.exe`, etc.  If I list pip's version while standing in that folder I get:

```
me@my-machine MINGW64 ~/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/Scripts (develop)
$ ./pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from c:\users\me\pycharmprojects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg\pip (python 3.7)

me@my-machine MINGW64 ~/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/Scripts (develop)
$ ./python --version
Python 3.7.1

me@my-machine MINGW64 ~/PycharmProjects/myProject/venv/Scripts (develop)
$ ./python -m pip --version
pip 18.1 from C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

I seem to have a version mismatch.  Can I safely delete the `pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg` folder?  Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't delete any files in your site-packages folder. Besides the two pip executables you tested are different. The one loaded with `python -m pip` will most probably point to the `pip3` binary and not the `pip` one.